# Fastest method to find indexes from bigint array

Tags: postgresql

I've got table with 50millions rows. I need to find every row with `id` from the array, but when I put in "ANY" statement more than 4 values my query lasts 45sec+. 4 and less values takes < 100ms.

What the fastest method to do the same thing:

`SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE id = ANY('{1, 12, 41, etc.}');`
or how to fix this behaviour?

`id` is a primary key

**upd**:

`account_id` is `id` from example above

**EXPLAIN(ANALYZE, BUFFERS) with 4 values:**

```
Gather  (cost=194818.11..14487783.08 rows=8426816 width=195) (actual time=62.011..67.316 rows=0 loops=1)
  Workers Planned: 2
  Workers Launched: 2
  Buffers: shared hit=16
  ->  Parallel Bitmap Heap Scan on player_match  (cost=193818.11..13644101.48 rows=3511173 width=195) (actual time=1.080..1.081 rows=0 loops=3)
        Recheck Cond: (account_id = ANY ('{4,6322,435,75}'::bigint[]))
        Buffers: shared hit=16
        ->  Bitmap Index Scan on player_match_pkey  (cost=0.00..191711.41 rows=8426816 width=0) (actual time=0.041..0.042 rows=0 loops=1)
              Index Cond: (account_id = ANY ('{4,6322,435,75}'::bigint[]))
              Buffers: shared hit=16
Planning Time: 0.118 ms
JIT:
  Functions: 6
  Options: Inlining true, Optimization true, Expressions true, Deforming true
  Timing: Generation 1.383 ms, Inlining 0.000 ms, Optimization 0.000 ms, Emission 0.000 ms, Total 1.383 ms
Execution Time: 67.925 ms
```

**with 5 values:**

```
Gather  (cost=1000.00..14995098.33 rows=10533520 width=195) (actual time=59544.067..59557.119 rows=0 loops=1)
  Workers Planned: 2
  Workers Launched: 2
  Buffers: shared hit=10327 read=11077591
  ->  Parallel Seq Scan on player_match  (cost=0.00..13940746.33 rows=4388967 width=195) (actual time=59498.932..59498.933 rows=0 loops=3)
        Filter: (account_id = ANY ('{4,6322,435,75,1}'::bigint[]))
        Rows Removed by Filter: 140446932
        Buffers: shared hit=10327 read=11077591
Planning Time: 0.137 ms
JIT:
  Functions: 6
  Options: Inlining true, Optimization true, Expressions true, Deforming true
  Timing: Generation 1.742 ms, Inlining 203.984 ms, Optimization 25.001 ms, Emission 20.096 ms, Total 250.823 ms
Execution Time: 59557.657 ms
```

upd2: fixed by `VACUUM(FULL, ANALYZE) tbl`;

Comment: I don't have a DB with 50M records at hand, so just suggesting via comment: what happens when you try `WHERE id IN (1, 12, 41)` instead of `ANY` ?

Comment: Please show an `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` output for the query with 4 values, and the one with 5 values.  Turn track_io_timing on first if you can and it is not already on.  Also, we need to know the version.

Comment: still with `EXPLAIN ANALYSE`, try this : `SELECT * FROM tbl INNER JOIN unnest ('{1, 12, 41, etc.}') AS a ON id = a`. The query plan may be different from the one you've got..

Comment: @jjanes edited my post. WHERE id IN  still the same

Comment: The estimates there are astonishingly bad.  Expected over 8 million, actually found 0. Has this table ever been ANALYZEd?  What stats does it have? `select * from pg_stats where tablename='player_match' and attname='account_id' \gx`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by

```
VACUUM(FULL, ANALYZE) tbl
```